# Show: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{6n+3}{3n+3}\neq 3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{6n+3}{3n+3}\neq 3$$

We have to show that there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $n\geq N$ s.t $|a_n-L|>\epsilon$

So

$$\left|\frac{6n+3}{3n+3}- 3\right|=\left|\frac{6n+3-9n-9}{3n+3}\right|=\left|\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}\right|$$

So
$$1=\left|\frac{-3n-3}{3n+3}\right|>\left|\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}\right|>\epsilon$$

For $\epsilon>1$ we will have the sequence diverges as for all $n$ we will have $$\left|\frac{6n+3}{3n+3}- 3\right|>1$$ is it ok?

Comment: Personally, I'd just show the limit is equal to $2$.

Comment: @Deepak I need to show the negation

Comment: The sequence is not divergent (in fact it approaches $2$). You're showing that the limit is not equal to $3$. For your proof, it's $\epsilon < 1$ that works, not $>1$.

Comment: You need to specify what $L$ denotes in your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{6n+3}{3n+3}-3\right|=\left|\frac3{3n+3}+1\right|>1$$

and indeed "*there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there is an $n\geq N$ such that $|a_n-3|>\epsilon$*" is made true by taking $\epsilon=1$ or smaller, and $n=N$. This proves the claim.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Prove that $\dfrac{6n+3}{3n+3}< \dfrac 52$
for all $n$. Then the limit is at most $\dfrac 52$ and so cannot be $3$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by $1<|(-3n-6)/(3n+3)|>\epsilon$.

You arrive at
$$
\left|\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}\right|
$$
and you can go on
$$
\left|\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}\right|=\left|\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right|=\left|1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right|>1
$$
So indeed you can choose $\epsilon=1$ and it even holds that *for every $n$*, $|a_n-3|>\epsilon$, so you can choose $N=0$ (or $N=1$ depending on where your natural numbers start from).

Comment: it should be $1=|\frac{-3n-3}{3n+3}|>|\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}|>\epsilon$

Comment: @newhere Why $1=$? By the way, $1>|(-3n-6)/(3n+3)|$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct. You seem to believe that you proved that the sequence diverges. That is false. It converges to $2$. And you did not explain the inequality$$\left\lvert\frac{-3n-3}{3n+3}\right\rvert<\left\lvert\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}\right\rvert.$$

Note that$$\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}=-1-\frac3{3n+3}=-1-\frac1{n+1}<-1.$$Therefore,$$\left\lvert\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}\right\rvert>1.$$So, if you take $\varepsilon=1$, the inequality$$\left\lvert\frac{-3n-6}{3n+3}\right\rvert<\varepsilon$$*never* holds.